# Sound, Video, and Ethernet drivers

Tags: wireless, sound, video

I'm a first time user of Ubuntu.
Where can I get the Sound, Video, and Ethernet drivers for Ubuntu 12.04.2?

Answer (score 1):

98% of the time they're part of the kernel package. Only if those don't work (or don't suffice) do you need to worry about getting external drivers.